# How to make a fql query in java?

Tags: java, facebook-fql

SELECT status_id, time, source, message FROM status WHERE uid = me(). I want to use this fql code in java. help me doing this.

Comment: Okay. Try this... `System.out.println("SELECT status_id, time, source, message FROM status WHERE uid = me()");`. That should put that in your code! :D

Comment: Your post doesnt seem to include any Java code, you should include it,

Comment: include your code and be a lot more detailed. btw, fql is deprecated since a very long time and will stop working soon.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what fql is but i do know what sql is. You need to download a connection driver, for example if connecting to MySQL, you can use JDBC. Afterwards you build a connection, then query in text and pull in values with a simple while(blah.next) loop. More examples of code can be found on java docs website. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html